# Robot_localization services /toLL and /fromLL respond with different result

Tags: navigation, gps, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the robot_localization package and in the terminal, I run the services **/fromLL** and **/toLL** for the same position. But the results do not agree.
Specifically, running:

```
rosservice call /robot/fromLL "ll_point:
  latitude: 40.5665059791
  longitude: 22.9989873398
  altitude: 122.0"
```

returns:

```
map_point: 
  x: 140892.72962
  y: 5405179.36945
  z: 0.0
```

And when I run:

```
rosservice call /robot/toLL "map_point:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0"
```

I get

```
ll_point: 
  latitude: 40.5665059791
  longitude: 22.9989873398
  altitude: 122.375866815
```

which is the same position as the first one.
I believe that this is not normal, but why is this happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369570/robot_localization-services-/toll-and-/fromll-respond-with-different-result/) by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 210 on 2021-01-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on 2021-01-14**:
Are your frame_id's the same? If the map point is in a different frame, you will have to do a tf_lookup and transform the point before using it.

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2021-01-14**:
I am running these services through the terminal, when running the node, so there is not a way to define in which frame each point is. For the first case, fromLL in what frame are we expecting the result to be for example?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2021-01-25**:
I'm guessing that first LL position that you used in the service call was not random. Where did you get it?

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2021-01-25**:
Yes, it was the current Lat/Long of the robot. If I'm not wrong there was a UTM->map transform at that time, using the navsat_transform.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2021-01-29**:
Can I ask what version you're using?

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2021-01-29**:
I am on ROS melodic and robot_localization has been installed using apt-get. Version 2.6.9 as mentioned in the package.xml file

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2021-01-29**:
Can you please head over to the GH repo and repost this as an issue, and please include your full config file, as well as maybe a bag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's a bug. [This](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/5d0ed1ecad24d797108fad17d3e6540bce567782/src/navsat_transform.cpp#L415) line has the `cartesian_x` and `cartesian_y` parameters backwards (`cartesian_y` should come first). Please file a ticket and I'll fix it. Thank you!

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2021-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2021-01-29**:
Alright, I will file an issue asap. Thanks a lot!